# Repeat function in Laravel / PHP Class in one shared function

Tags: php

With the following code, how do I place the on_stats function in one area?  So it can be shared and called in all functions on this page instead of copying and pasting the same code over and over again. Also how do I declare $logger just once instead of over and over again.

```
class API extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function api_call1() {
     $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['defaults' => ['verify' => false]]);
             $logger = new Logger('View Logs');
 $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(storage_path() . '/logs/api_log.log', Logger::INFO));


     $res = $client->get($this->url . "/my/url/", [
             'on_stats'  => function (TransferStats $stats) use ($logger) {
                $logger->info('Request' . $stats->getRequest()->getMethod() . 
                               'Response' . $stats->getResponse()->getStatusCode() .
                               'Tx Time' . $stats->getTransferTime()
                );
            }
        ]);
        $response = Response::make($res->getBody(), 200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
        }

            public function api_call2() {
     $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['defaults' => ['verify' => false]]);

                         $logger = new Logger('View Logs');
 $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(storage_path() . '/logs/api_log.log', Logger::INFO));


     $res = $client->get($this->url . "/my/url2/", [
             'on_stats'  => function (TransferStats $stats) use ($logger) {
                $logger->info('Request' . $stats->getRequest()->getMethod() . 
                               'Response' . $stats->getResponse()->getStatusCode() .
                               'Tx Time' . $stats->getTransferTime()
                );
            }
        ]);
        $response = Response::make($res->getBody(), 200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my viewpoint, it would be a great idea to:

1. Declare a class property as $logger
2. Move logger initialization to the constructor
3. Rewrite the "on_stats" method as a class method, say `logEvent(TransferStats $stats)` using $this->logger, this way you can avoid using "`use`" keyword
4. Pass the client event "`on_stats`" as a standard PHP callable array:

   ['on_stats' => [$this, 'logEvent']]